# Trazer descrição de um enum - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, enums

Eu preciso trazer a descrição de um enum, existe algum método genérico que me traga a descrição do enum ao invés do valor dele?

```
    <?php

namespace App\Business\Logistica\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Contracts\LocalizedEnum;
use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

class EventoLogisticaEnum extends Enum implements LocalizedEnum
{
    const VIAGEM = 5;
    const SERVICO = 6;
    const ENTREGA_OU_COLETA = 7;
    const CONCRETO = 8;
    const CONCRETOBOMBA = 9;
//    const BOMBA = 10;
//    const PIPA = 11;

    /**
     * @param $valor
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getBackground($valor): string
    {
        switch ($valor) {
            case self::VIAGEM:
                return "warning";
            case self::SERVICO:
                return "danger";
            case self::ENTREGA_OU_COLETA:
                return "success";
            case self::CONCRETO;
                return "primary";
            case self::CONCRETOBOMBA;
                return "primary";
            default:
                return "success";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

atualmente eu consigo trazer os valores para exibir na view, exemplo:
5
6
7
8

mas quero retornar os nomes, que é a descrição, exemplo:
VIAGEM
SERVIÇO
ENTREGA_OU_COLETA
CONCRETO

para isso preciso de um metodo que deve ter na propria biblioteca do enum para pegar isso, exemplo:

Enum::pegaNomeEnumIgual(5)
e ele retorna o nome viagem.

**Como pegar o valor sem precisar adicionar um novo método?
Não quero poluir a classe.**

Comment: Quando diz descrição refere-se ao que em concreto ? Pode dar um exemplo ?

Comment: estou pesquisando e vi que tem um metodo que traz o nome da constante que vc atribuiu ao valor, porém não consigo saber qual é, a IDE também não ajuda.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Existe um métado nativo do Laravel que é o:

```
EventoLogisticaEnum::getDescription();
```

Caso a descição não seja a esperada, você pode ir em resources/lang/pt/enums
e adicionar uma descrição, algo assim:

```
<?php

return [
    EventoLogisticaEnum::class => [
            EventoLogisticaEnum::ENTREGA_OU_COLETA => 'Entrega ou Coleta',
            EventoLogisticaEnum::CONCRETOBOMBA=> 'Concreto Bomba',
            EventoLogisticaEnum::VIAGEM=> 'Viagem'
        ]
];
```

Você pode procurar saber mais em: https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum